# Is there a web app that emulates the iPhone browser?

Tags: iphone, html, browser, emulation

I'm trying to get an iPhone browser emulator to work on my website so it will work on all platforms. Are there any Javascript snippets that emulate the iPhone browser? I need it to zoom and browse the web, but the bookmark function is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a thing, as the iOS browser has a number of differences to any desktop browser.

The closest you could have is an iFrame surrounded by a picture of an iPhone, and instruct people to use Safari 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, you can use the iOS Simulator. Download Xcode from the App Store and with it comes the iOS Simulator, which also has the Safari app virtually exactly as is on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.browserstack.com/ does exactly that.    It ain't perfect, but it works..